# nifi JoinEnrichment returns only original

Tags: apache-nifi

Im trying to use JoinEnrichment, but dont get the enrichment in the result, just the original. I was trying to use all enrichment modes with same result.

[image: nifi flow desinition]

Log:

```
2023-07-13 09:33:56,462 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-9] o.a.n.processors.standard.LogAttribute LogAttribute[id=103c1277-1040-10c7-9cc8-e23dbb000fba] logging for flow file StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=62500046-90e4-4b96-a973-1d9dc2c8852e,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1689240288569-126, container=default, section=126], offset=19896, length=120],offset=0,name=c02d147c-d9ab-4b44-8963-6fb31f4fbf93,size=120]
--------------------------------------------------
FlowFile Attribute Map Content
Key: 'enrichment.group.id'
    Value: '16086913-2fe8-4a12-9937-8d4eadb642b4'
Key: 'enrichment.role'
    Value: 'ORIGINAL'
--------------------------------------------------
{
  "cisloParcely" : "4401/2",
  "celkovaVymeraParcely" : 1940,
  "listVlastnictva" : 5242,
  "druhPozemku" : "Vinica"
}
2023-07-13 09:33:59,502 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-5] o.a.n.processors.standard.LogAttribute LogAttribute[id=103c1277-1040-10c7-9cc8-e23dbb000fba] logging for flow file StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=42faa4e1-67bd-44fb-98a8-1b0f2a34c3ca,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1689240288569-126, container=default, section=126], offset=20016, length=995],offset=0,name=c02d147c-d9ab-4b44-8963-6fb31f4fbf93,size=995]
--------------------------------------------------
FlowFile Attribute Map Content
Key: 'enrichment.group.id'
    Value: '16086913-2fe8-4a12-9937-8d4eadb642b4'
Key: 'enrichment.role'
    Value: 'ENRICHMENT'
--------------------------------------------------
{
  "uzivatelia" : [ {
    "meno" : "XYZ",
    "podielVlastnikaCitatel" : 1,
    "podielVlastnikaMenovatel" : 6,
    "typVlastnika" : "Vlastník",
    "poradieVlastnika" : 1
  }, {
    "meno" : "XYZ",
    "podielVlastnikaCitatel" : 1,
    "podielVlastnikaMenovatel" : 6,
    "typVlastnika" : "Vlastník",
    "poradieVlastnika" : 2
  }, {
    "meno" : "XYZ",
    "podielVlastnikaCitatel" : 1,
    "podielVlastnikaMenovatel" : 3,
    "typVlastnika" : "Vlastník",
    "poradieVlastnika" : 3
  }, {
    "meno" : "XYZ",
    "podielVlastnikaCitatel" : 1,
    "podielVlastnikaMenovatel" : 3,
    "typVlastnika" : "Vlastník",
    "poradieVlastnika" : 4
  }, {
    "meno" : "XYZ",
    "podielVlastnikaCitatel" : 0,
    "podielVlastnikaMenovatel" : 0,
    "typVlastnika" : "Správca",
    "poradieVlastnika" : 5
  } ]
}
2023-07-13 09:34:00,002 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-2] o.a.n.processors.standard.LogAttribute LogAttribute[id=103c1277-1040-10c7-9cc8-e23dbb000fba] logging for flow file StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=939b4716-9200-417e-b400-1bf58a471b9b,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1689240359382-127, container=default, section=127], offset=24779, length=153],offset=0,name=4e267690-2917-4f90-b974-90fe0ea4f618,size=153]
--------------------------------------------------
FlowFile Attribute Map Content
Key: 'enrichment.group.id'
    Value: '16086913-2fe8-4a12-9937-8d4eadb642b4'
--------------------------------------------------
[ {
  "original" : {
    "cisloParcely" : "4401/2",
    "celkovaVymeraParcely" : 1940,
    "listVlastnictva" : 5242,
    "druhPozemku" : "Vinica"
  }
} ]
```

Thank you

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Comment: I think that `original` relationship from `Fork` processor should be directly connected to `Join` processor

Comment: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.22.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ForkEnrichment/additionalDetails.html

Comment: tried that as well with same result

Comment: Is there some error?

Comment: nope, just the enrichment missing in the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created and tested a similar flow on the latest version NiFi (`1.22.0`) and worked!
[template](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tonykoval/246aca6c1d312d7fe9492cf5742e9684/raw/be4ffd0163a0a9bf3973bf5a977b401a093e21d1/test.xml)

I suggest upgrading NiFi (`1.20.0` to `1.22.0`)